# Display alert notification even app is closed

Tags: java, android

The app is fetching alert data from server. What I have to do is display the notification if app will get new alert. This should be happen even app is closed. Previously, I have worked on push notification where server is used to display the notification. But here I don't want to use push notification. So is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[Notification API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)**. Notification is a message you can display to the user outside of your application's normal UI. When you tell the system to issue a notification, it first appears as an icon in the notification area. To see the details of the notification, the user opens the notification drawer. Both the notification area and the notification drawer are system-controlled areas that the user can view at any time.

Comment: Thank you Diego, Can you please refer me related blog or example for mentioned scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You might require a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to accomplish your needs. Use a Service with the mentioned [Notification API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to send notifications even when the app is 'closed'.

Comment: i5H4N can you suggest me some link related to this particular example.

Comment: @u_pendra Sure. But first can you elaborate a bit more on your requirements? I'm assuming that you're fetching some data from a server in the background and when the data fetch is complete you want a notification to be dispalyed?

You can start by reading about background services.
These should cover your need:
1. To create a background service - http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
2. To create a notification - http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: yes you r right, I have to continue fetch alert from sever, whenever new alert come it should show the notification. Same like we are getting Gmail notification in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

no other way to this without using push notification and GCM

Comment: can you elaborate why?

Comment: because GCM is the only to connect to server and retrieve data from server. You can check from using below link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/